# How does the $\phi(x_i)$ function look for Gaussian RBF kernel?

Tags: svm, kernel-trick

I am trying to write programs for simple SVM cases. And what I am stuck at is that I am unable to find $\phi(x_i)$ functions for given kernels.

For example there is Gaussian Radial Basis Function (RBF) kernel:

$$K(x_i,x_j)=\mathrm{exp}\left( \|x_j-x_i\|^2\right),$$

but to compute SVM's weights I also need $\phi(x_i)$, as

$$w=\sum_{i=1}^{N_{SV}} \alpha_i d_i \phi(x_i).$$

Is there something I am missing, as in not even one book I have found $\phi(x_i)$ for a given $K$?

Comment: Here you find a more 'intuitive' explanation that the $\Phi$ can map onto a spave of dimension equal to the size of the training sample, even for an infinite training sample: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80398/svm-in%EF%AC%81nite-dimensional-feature-space/168309#168309

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing one thing, namely the fact that *we do not need to know the images of data instances in feature space $\phi(\mathbf{x}_i)$*. For some kernel functions, the feature space is very complex/unknown (for instance some graph kernels), or infinite dimensional (for example the RBF kernel).

Kernel methods only need to be able to compute *inner products between two images in feature space*, e.g. $\kappa(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j)=\langle\phi(\mathbf{x}_i),\phi(\mathbf{x}_j)\rangle$. We don't have to know the feature space to be able to compute inner products in it. This is called the [kernel trick](http://www.eric-kim.net/eric-kim-net/posts/1/kernel_trick.html).

---

For an SVM, specifically, $\mathbf{w}$ is the separating hyperplane *in feature space*. You cannot always write this down in input space. Again, for the RBF kernel $\mathbf{w}$ resides in an infinite dimensional feature space. All we need to be able to do is compute the inner product of $\mathbf{w}$ and the image of the test instance $\mathbf{z}$ in feature space $\phi(\mathbf{z}$), which is:

$$\langle\mathbf{w},\phi(\mathbf{z})\rangle = \sum_{i\in SV}\alpha_i y_i \kappa(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{z}).$$

SVMs exploit the so-called [representer theorem](http://alex.smola.org/papers/2001/SchHerSmo01.pdf), which states that the resulting models can always be expressed as a weighted sum of kernel evaluations between some training instances (the support vectors) and the test instance. This is in fact exploited by all kernel methods.

---

The RBF kernel maps onto an infinite dimensional feature space. For a writeup on this you may consult [these slides by Chih-Jen Lin](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/talks/kuleuven_svm.pdf), particularly slides 10 and 11. For a one-dimensional $x$:

$$\phi_{RBF}(x) = e^{-\gamma x^2}\big[1,\sqrt{\frac{2\gamma}{1!}}x, \sqrt{\frac{(2\gamma)^2}{2!}}x^2, \sqrt{\frac{(2\gamma)^3}{3!}}x^3,\ldots\big]^T,$$

which follows from the Taylor expansion of the exponential function.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I find $b$ in $y(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{N_{SV}}\alpha_i d_i K(x_i,x)+b$?

Comment: This is an old question, but how would the feature map look in the $d$-dimensional case?