# How do the mapping function phi(x) of a RBF kernel?

Tags: svm, kernel-trick, rbf-network, structured-svm

I'm trying to implement a paper that used SVM and an improve of it with Bayesian decision theory. How do I do the mapping feature $\phi(x)$ that appears in the decision function?

[image: Decision function]

The paper used an RBF kernel, I have the kernel from the Mercer, with the inner product of the vector x.

[image]

But I do not understand how to do the function $\phi(x)$.

Comment: A question very similar to your own is http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/122631/9964. Note also that the $\varphi$ function is discussed more at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/69759/9964 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/35634/9964.

Answer (score 1):

$\phi(x)$ is implied by the kernel $k$. So, in general, you don't have access to $\phi$. This is a remarkable property of kernels. For example, the popular RBF kernel has a corresponding $\phi$ that is infinite dimensional (and so cannot be computed directly).

You might have a hard time improving the SVM with anything Bayesian... the magic of the SVM is that the optimization reduces $\phi$ to computing inner products in the reproducing kernel Hilbert space implied by $\phi$... Thus, you never have to calculate $\phi$, which is usually computationally intractable. That said, you can use your Bayesian methods with most convex non-linearities (and just put that in place of $\phi$). But be aware that the computational complexity tends explode... Or you could just do the whole neural network thing and throw convexity out the window and learn $\phi$ (i.e., the neural network).